# Group and summarize with iterative filter using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Upfront apology if this has been asked, I have been searching all day and have not found an answer I can apply to my problem.

I am trying to solve this issue using dplyr (and co.) because my previous method (for loops) was too inefficient. I have a dataset of event times, at sites, that are in groups. I want to summarize the number (and proportion) of events that occur in a moving window along a sequence.

```
# Example data
set.seed(1)
sites = rep(letters[1:10],10)
groups = c('red','blue','green','yellow')
times = round(runif(length(sites),1,100))

timePeriod = seq(1,100)

# Example dataframe
df = data.frame(site = sites,
                group = rep(groups,length(sites)/length(groups)),
                time = times)
```

This is my attempt to  summarize the number of sites from each group that contain a time (event) within a given moving window of time. 
The goal is to move through each element of the vector `timePeriod` and summarize how many events in each group occurred at `timePeriod[i] +/- half-window`. Ultimately storing them in, e.g., a dataframe with a column for each group, and a row for each time step, is ideal.

```
df %>%
filter(time > timePeriod[i]-25 & time < timePeriod[i]+25) %>%
group_by(group) %>%
summarise(count = n())
```

How can I do this without looping through my sequence of time and storing the summary table for each group individually? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining `lapply` and `dplyr`, you can do the following, which is close to what you had worked so far.

```
lapply(timePeriod, function(i){
  df %>%
    filter(time > (i - 25) & time < ( i + 25 ) )  %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>% 
    mutate(step = i)
}) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Great, thank you @Juan Bosco! I am still learning how to implement the apply family, great example.