# Summarizing with overlapping groups using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the best way to create overlapping groups using dplyr?

For example, imagine you have the following data set

```
test <- data.frame(year = rep(as.character(2014:2016), 2), value = 1:6)
```

And you want to summarize using a group for each year, and then full period.
Two ways to do this could be as follows:

Using bind_rows and mutate (and probably filter in a more complex example)

```
year.totals <- bind_rows(test %>% mutate(year = "2014:2016"),
                         test) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarize(value = sum(value))
```

Using gather

```
year.totals.2 <- test %>% 
  mutate(year.2 = "2014:2016") %>% 
  gather(drop, year, year, year.2) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarize(value = sum(value))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I've also seen [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498326/group-and-summarize-with-iterative-filter-using-dplyr), which I don't think is too bad but I would prefer to avoid the lapply.

Comment: You can do this in `base R` i.e. `addmargins(rowsum(test$value, test$year), 1)`

Comment: I want something that will work with a more complex example too such as where a group could be "2014:2015" and the summary statistic could be an average, or a weighted average etc.

Comment: I asked a very similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/39106850/4269699) though it's a bit more general. tl;dr - `dplyr` doesn't have this functionality explicitly. I still use the `bind_rows()` approach in the absence of anything better

Comment: This is a post I made about the gather method [https://colintb.github.io/overlapping_groups-example/](https://colintb.github.io/overlapping_groups-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create "rolling groups" and summarize by those. I've used the `map` function from the `purrr` package (which, like `dplyr`, is one of the `tidyverse` packages).

First, let's create two helper functions. Depending on your needs, you can generalize these to allow flexible choice of grouping column(s), choice of summary statistics, etc.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create rolling year groups
year.groups = function(start.years, n) {
  ll = length(start.years)
  start.years = sort(start.years[-c((ll-(n-2)):ll)])
  map(as.numeric(as.character(start.years)), function(x) x:(x+(n-1)))
}

# Summarise by rolling group
roll.group = function(vec) {
   vec %>% map_df(~ test %>% 
         filter(year %in% .x) %>%
         group_by(year = paste(year[which.min(year)], year[which.max(year)], sep="-")) %>%
         summarise(value=sum(value)))
}
```

Now summarize by rolling group:

```
# Summarise by rolling year group and individual years
bind_rows(year.groups(unique(test$year), 2) %>% 
            roll.group(),
          year.groups(unique(test$year), 3) %>%
            roll.group(),
          test %>% group_by(year) %>%
            summarise(value=sum(value)))
```

> ```
>        year value
> 1 2014-2015    12
> 2 2015-2016    16
> 3 2014-2016    21
> 4      2014     5
> 5      2015     7
> 6      2016     9
> ```

You asked for the "best" way to create overlapping groups in `dplyr`. I'd be surprised if this is the best way, but at least it seems to be *a* way.